# AWS Cognito Amplify + Angular : Login using Username/instead email-id

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am creating a custom Login, registration form in angular. I want to login using username, not the email id , is there a way to do so?
Code reference would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done .

The setting needs to be done while creating a userPool in aws Cognito .

In the attributes tab , One needs to check the checkboxes containing
the following.

- Also allow sign in with verified email address
- Also allow sign in with preferred username (a username that your
  users can change).

This way , a user can sign in by both email address and  the user name .
[image]

Comment: ok, how can that be handled from angular end as well as how can we add validation check to the username so that there are no redundant username.